# Using hibernate event listeners to update denormalised values in other entities

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a hibernate based application.

This application is already using an interceptor to trigger the creation of an audit trail; it does this by hooking the 'beforeTransactionComplete' machinery, to copy the finalized state of each entity into an audit table.

All entities have a version number that is incremented when a change occurs - this protects against conflicting updates, as the audit table has a PK of ID + Version.

This works very well. What we are now trying to do is implement some schema performance enhancements by de-normalizing some entity data. We have these hibernate-backed entities :

```
public class Task {
  boolean isCompleted;
  // ...
}

public class Allocation {
  Resource resource; 
  Task task;
  boolean taskIsCompleted; // <-- this is a new field
}
```

(There may, potentially, be many allocations each referring to the same task).

The taskIsCompleted field is a recommendation from the DBA - to duplicate the isCompleted value from the task, so that querying can avoid joining to Task simply to discover whether isCompleted = false.

One approach to achieve this is to use a database trigger on the update of task. However, this is unacceptable for our usecase, as a) Triggers tie us to a particular database implementation, but b) it is completed 'behind the back' of the auditing trigger - so that field will be adjusted without the other auditing features being engaged correctly. We must have this entity updated 'as if' the business logic had updated it manually.

So, I was hoping this could be achieved with Event Listeners in hibernate. But I am unsure as to how 'safe' this approach is, and there are a number of issues.

My approach has been to register listeners on SaveOrUpdateEventListener and FlushEntityEventListener, doing something like:

```
public void onFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event) throws HibernateException {
    if( event.getEntity() instanceof Task) {

        // Find all the allocations for this task
        Session session = event.getSession();
        Query hq = session.createQuery("from Allocation alloc where alloc.task.id = :id");
        hq.setParameter("id", task.getId());
        Collection<Allocation> allocations =  hq.list();

        // And update them
        for( Allocation allocation : allocations ) {
           allocation.setTaskComplete( task.getIsCompleted() );
           session.save(allocation);
        }

    }
}
```

the first problem is that performing the query here causes hibernate to 're-flush' all the entities, causing an eventual stack overflow (I.E: hq.list() causes a flush, which calls onFlushEntity, which....).

I can probably guard against that, by keeping a list of 'already flushed' tasks, but in my initial attempts I'm also seeing failures in the auditing (whereby it's attempting to duplicate the row twice).

Are there any examples of doing this sort of thing in Hibernate? I'm mostly concerned that I'll be able to hack it together, but miss some important edge-case that fails in production when I'm least expecting it..

Update:
It seems that performing the query *really* confuses things. Hibernate re-calls 'onFlushEntity' in order to (presumably) try to write the Task back to the database before the query -- however, the SQL Update never actually happens..