# Database access in Hibernate listeners

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

Let's say there are entities like `Thing` and `ThingItem` with an 1:N relationship. Imagine that there are hundreds of items and they have some attributes which are important and tedious to set. There should be some `ThingBackup` gathering all changes to all items belonging to a single `Thing` (they get written as a blob for simplicity).

I'm doing it using [hibernate listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501074/hibernate-interceptor-and-event-listeners), so that I don't have to add code to all program parts doing the change. It works well, but I don't know how to ensure consistency.

I thought, I'd use `POST_UPDATE` (as opposed to `POST_COMMIT_UPDATE`), so that both the items and the backup get written in the same transaction.

The problem is that in a `PostUpdateEventListener`, doing `session.createCriteria(ThingBackup.class). ... .uniqueResult()` leads to a `ConcurrentModificationException` in hibernate. The problem seems to be that the listeners get called from a loop iterating the list of changes and this very list gets modified when accessing the database (even on a read access as it requires some flushing).

I'd call it a bug, thought it does not violate the specification (given exactly zero lines of Javadoc, there's not much to violate). It may get fixed one day or not, I need a workaround. It looks like an older version of hibernate manifested a [different bug in this place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22248206/581205).

I can create another session and use it for the needed work (read the `ThingBackup`, modify it and write it back). However, this way I get two transactions and, in case the one closed last fails, an inconsistency.

*Is there a solution? Or am I maybe doing something wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc of [`Interceptor`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html):

> The `Session` may not be invoked from a callback (nor may a callback
>   cause a collection or proxy to be lazily initialized).

[The same is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312078/hibernate-jpa-entity-listener-pre-and-post-dont-work-as-expected) for JPA entity lifecycle callbacks.

As a solution you may want to take a look at [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) which provides auditing of entity changes.

Comment: You're right. The documentation for events is well hidden, when you look for it. Envers uses some do-it-later-before-commit-job, which is what I did, too.